# Send recycler view data into a json

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

[Attendance Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgosB.png)

I am creating an application for Student Attendance I get data from Server as students details, Now I want to get values of radio present(green) or absent(red) with admission no how can I do this.
Sorry for my English

Here is the JSON format which I am going to send back to the server as attendance details

```
{
"Date": "",
"ClassRSN": "",
"SectionRSN": "",
"SessionRSN": "",
"Studentdetails": [
    {
        "AdmissionID": "",
        "Attendance": ""
    }
]}
```

I am unable to iterate every value

recyclerView class

```
public class StudentDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
Integer attendance;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> StudentDetailList;

public StudentDetailsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Studetails) {
    this.context = context;
    StudentDetailList = Studetails;
    Log.e("MD", "" + Studetails);
}


@Override
public StudentDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_row_student_details, parent, false);
    return new StudentDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StudentDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    } else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAF8FD"));

    }

    holder.tvrollno.setText(StudentDetailList.get(position).get("stu_no"));
    holder.tvname.setText(StudentDetailList.get(position).get("stu_name"));

    if (holder.rdBtnPresent.isChecked()) {
        attendance = 1;
    } else {
        attendance = 0;
    }
    try {
        // Creating JSONObject from String
        JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(ConstantClass.myjsonstring);
        Log.e("jsonObjMain", "jsonObjMain" + jsonObjMain);
        jsonObjMain.put("Date", "30-11-2018");
        jsonObjMain.put("ClassRSN", "1");
        jsonObjMain.put("SectionRSN", "1");
        jsonObjMain.put("SessionRSN", "13");


        JSONArray quesans = new JSONArray(jsonObjMain.getString("Studentdetails"));
        for (int i = 0; i < StudentDetailList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject studata = quesans.getJSONObject(i);
            studata.put("AdmissionID", StudentDetailList.get(position).get("stu_no"));
            studata.put("Attendance",StudentDetailList.get(position).attendance);

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return StudentDetailList.size();

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvrollno, tvname;
    RadioButton rdBtnPresent, rdBtnAbsent;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvrollno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rollno);
        tvname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        rdBtnPresent = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendance_present);
        rdBtnAbsent = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendance_absent);


    }
}}
```

MainActivity

```
public class Attendance extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> StudentList = new ArrayList<>();
Calendar myCalendar1;
RecyclerView rdrecyclerView;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date1;
EditText etAttDAte;
Spinner classpinner, sectionspinner;
List<SpinnerBean> block;
Button btnGo;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> StudentDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
LinearLayout LL_studeatils;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_class);

    SetIDs();
    SpinnerData();


    InVokeDatePicker();
    getSystemDate();
}

public void InVokeDatePicker() {
    myCalendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    date1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel1();
        }

    };


    etAttDAte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(Attendance.this, date1, myCalendar1
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

}

private void updateLabel1() {
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    etAttDAte.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar1.getTime()));

}

public void getSystemDate() {
    Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c);
    etAttDAte.setText(formattedDate);
}

public void SpinnerData() {
    final List<SpinnerBean> dist = UtilityClass.getAllDistrict(Attendance.this);
    classpinner.setAdapter(new StateListAdapter(Attendance.this, dist));

    classpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SpinnerBean bean = (SpinnerBean) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dist.get(i).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ConstantClass.GetClass = dist.get(i).getId();
            block = UtilityClass.getDistricWiseBlock(Attendance.this, dist.get(i).getId());
            sectionspinner.setAdapter(new StateListAdapter(Attendance.this, block));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });
    sectionspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SpinnerBean bean = (SpinnerBean) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), block.get(i).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ConstantClass.GetSection = block.get(i).getId();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });
}

public void SetIDs() {
    rdrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recView);
    etAttDAte = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.attendance_date);
    classpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_class);
    sectionspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_section);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
    LL_studeatils = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL_studetailsView);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StudentDetailsList.clear();
            LL_studeatils.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new SendPostRequest().execute();
        }
    });
}

class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            java.net.URL url = new URL("http://mindfacttech.com/api/SchoolERPAPITemp/BL/StudentManager.php"); // here is your URL path
            Log.e("url", "" + url);

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("ClassRSN", ConstantClass.GetClass);
            postDataParams.put("SectionRSN", ConstantClass.GetSection);
            postDataParams.put("studentlist", "yes");
            Log.e("postDataParams", "" + postDataParams);


            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            } else {
                return new String("false : " + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("result", "" + result);
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.e("ConstantClass.resJSon", "" + jo);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jo.getString("Students"));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> reqedetails = new HashMap<>();

                reqedetails.put("stu_no", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AdmissionNo"));
                reqedetails.put("stu_name", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                String s1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AdmissionNo");
                Log.e("s1", "" + s1);
                StudentDetailsList.add(reqedetails);
                Log.e("StudentDetailsList.....", "" + StudentDetailsList);
            }


            rdrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false));
            rdrecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rdrecyclerView.setAdapter(new StudentDetailsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), StudentDetailsList));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }

    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {

            String key = itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
public void getjsondata() {
    // Reading json file from assets folder
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                "Student.json")));
        String temp;
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(temp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //                br.close(); // stop reading
    }
    ConstantClass.myjsonstring = sb.toString();}}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: @vikrantarankalle plz find I edited my question

Comment: On CLicking the radio button update the ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> StudentDetailList, then convert the ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> StudentDetailList to json using gson library and reflection

Comment: can you plz make change @akshay

Comment: @PrateekGupta use Radio group in staid of radio button and add event listener on it and according to event change your arraylist data

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

Do some changes here.

```
//make jsonarray called "Studentdetails" and put it into your main json object.
JSONArray quesans = new JSONArray(jsonObjMain.getString("Studentdetails")); //  not requred
for (int i = 0; i < StudentDetailList.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject studata = new JSONOject();
        studata.put("AdmissionID", StudentDetailList.get(position).get("stu_no"));
        studata.put("Attendance",StudentDetailList.get(position).attendance);
        jsonObjMain.accumulate("Studentdetails" , studata);   // add this
    }
```

Comment: how to get attendance of each student with their AdmissionID

Comment: Can you tell me what you had done for getting attendance of the students I mean have you made class for students or static array or taking input at runtime.

Comment: I got students details from the API & wants to get attendance of each

Answer (score 0):

You are making the Json object in the onBindView??! ,every scroll will add/rewrite to the json data. Your app will lag I guess. Do this Make a model class with all the student attributes with getters and setters. Make arraylist of that model class. Show it in the recyclerview. After user has marked the attendance simply return the arraylist to the activity containing the recyclerview using a method in your adapter. Then use the gson library to make the json data for u from the arraylist.

Comment: Sure! do you have an example

Comment: Its hard to find an example having everything. 

Make your `Student` model using online tool http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. Make a ArrayList of student and show using recyclerview.

Set a onclick listener in your inner `ViewHolder` adapter class there u can set student.setAttendance(true/false) for every student.

Get the list/arraylist of Student using a simple return statement.

Use gson to change arraylist to json for posting 
`Gson gson = new Gson();
String post_this = gson.toJson(studentarraylist);`

Comment: I am unable to get exact code can you plz it for me

Comment: this will take time.You will eventually learn it anyhow. For now initialize another hashmap, `Hashmap<Integer,Integer> attendanceMap` for rollnumber & attendance in adapter.
set onclick on recyclerview using https://hackernoon.com/android-recyclerview-onitemclicklistener-getadapterposition-a-better-way-3c789baab4db

in onclick put (rollnumber,attendance) & make a method in the adapter

`public Hashmap<Int,Int> getAttendancemap(){
return attendanceMap;
}`

here make sure the radio button have a default state say `absent` or check against number of studens to prevent partial data.